# Bot Dialog Action button issue node.js

Tags: dialog, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to create bot for MS Teams via Microsoft Bot Framework using some examples from the Internet.

I have created user card that has button "See Report"

```
function userCard(session, connector, name, workingStatus, TeamsID) {

    var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
        .title(name)
        .subtitle(workingStatus.toString())
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, 'userReport', TeamsID, 'See Report')
        ]);
    return card;
}
```

Card is displayed without any issues. When I press on button it should trigger new dialog

```
//Begins the userReport dialog if the button on the userCard is pressed
bot.beginDialogAction('userReport', '/userReport');
```

This functionality works perfect when I test it in Bot Framework Emulator. 
In MS Teams instead of triggering userReport dialog it goes to the main dialog (the one that is used when message is sent). So that this button does not work at all.

Could you, please, advise what should be adjusted/added in order to make this button work in MS Teams?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank goodness you're just getting started. It looks like you're using Bot Framework V3, which is severely outdated. You should definitely switch to [V4](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js).

Teams has it's own additional trickiness. I recommend trying out and combing through each of these samples:

- [57.teams-conversation-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot)
- [07.using-adaptive-cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/07.using-adaptive-cards)

Then read through the [Adaptive Cards blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/).

Basically, a response from an Adaptive Card comes back in `activity.value`, so in `onTurn()`, you'll want to use an `if` statement to watch `activity.value` for the value sent in your Adaptive Card when the user clicks "See Report". Then, use `beginDialog` or `dialog.run()`, as appropriate to start your dialog.

Comment: @StandardUser Good to hear! I always recommend V4 over V3, but I'm very glad you were just getting started; less work for you!